# Why does C# compiler emit additional OpCodes in IL?

Tags: c#, cil, il, opcode

If I've a method `Multiply` defined as:

```
public static class Experiment
{
    public static int Multiply(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Then why does the compiler emit this IL:

```
.method public hidebysig static int32 Multiply(int32 a, int32 b) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 2              //why is it not 16?
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 CS$1$0000) //what is this?
    L_0000: nop              //why this?
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: ldarg.1 
    L_0003: mul 
    L_0004: stloc.0          //why this?
    L_0005: br.s L_0007      //why this?
    L_0007: ldloc.0          //why this?
    L_0008: ret 
}
```

As you can see, it also contains some additional OpCodes which don't make sense to me, when in fact I expect the following IL:

```
.method public hidebysig static int32 MyMethod(int32 a, int32 b) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 16
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldarg.1 
    L_0002: mul 
    L_0003: ret 
}
```

which does the very same thing.

So the question is, why does the compiler emit additional OpCodes in IL?

I'm using Debug mode.

Comment: Debug or Release configuration?

Comment: At least the `NOP` is debug only and creates some kind of sequence point over which the JITter may not reorder instructions. This helps with debugging.

Comment: I'm assuming you recompiled in Release mode after the above question by @Alex?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Yes. It isn't containing them anymore. But still I'm curious about the debug mode build, and emitted IL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mostly for debugging & breakpoint support; See an answer here: [Why are these nop instructions in my debug build?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zelmalki/archive/2008/12/11/why-is-the-nop-instruction-in-my-debug-build.aspx)