# Application's performance deteriorates when running it from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have an application in C#, which connects to a database and generates some Excel report.

When I run the application inside Visual Studio in Debug mode, this operation takes approx. 101736 milliseconds.

When I open the *bin\Debug* folder and run the executable from there, that same process (same database, same parameters) takes 33135 milliseconds.

But I'm running the same program.

What can be causing such a huge difference in performance?

I've done this several times, running the application from Visual Studio is always much more slower than running the executable from Windows Explorer.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 C# Express Edition.

Comment: It's the debugger that track your application

Comment: its probably the attached debugger in VS.

Comment: What happens when you run as `Ctrl + F5`

Comment: @V4Vendetta When I do it using Ctrl-F5 the time is equal to 33224.

Answer (score 4):

The primary causes of slowdown in the Visual Studio debugger are the following:

1. **Large numbers of P/Invoke calls.** There are about 100x slower when the P/Invoke MDA is enabled (which is the case when the debugger is attached, even if no breakpoints are set). The overhead is a fixed amount for every P/Invoke method invocation, so if a single P/Invoke execution is slow then you won't notice a difference, but if your method is doing something like `return a+b;` and called hundreds of thousands of times, you'll get hit hard.
2. **Tracepoints and/or conditional breakpoints.** These are only slow when they are actually getting hit. Tracepoints are hard to "hide" since you can see their output, but I've seen cases where conditional breakpoints were executed millions of times leading to very slow execution in the debugger.

   - Note: regular (unconditional) breakpoints are extremely fast, with little to no overhead in the debugger.
3. **IntelliTrace call tracing mode enabled (applies to Visual Studio 2010 and newer, Ultimate Edition).** IntelliTrace has two settings: events mode is fast but call tracing mode can pose a significant overhead.
4. **Large numbers of exceptions getting thrown.** If your application is throwing many thousands of exceptions, then you may see a slowdown in the debugger.
5. **Trace and/or Debug output.** If your application is calling `Debug.WriteLine` or `Trace.WriteLine` many (read: thousands of) times, it could slow your application down while attached to the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Running from visual studio causes a lot of debugging process to run along with it. This enables you to break at certain points and examine the local variables (among many other things). If you compile a release version the improvement would likely be even more marked as visual studio then compiles with the optimizer flag enabled.

Answer (score 0):

its probably the attached debugger in VS.

If you have a lot of console output or first chance exceptions, you will get a considerable slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging can slow down execution quite a lot. If you choose "Start Without Debugging" the performance should be the same as when you execute the file outside of Visual Studio.

Some things to avoid that slow the execution down even more *during debugging compared to executing the file directly*:

- Breakpoints that are conditional (they cause the condition to be evaluated)
- Exceptions
- Specifying external symbols to be loaded
- Code that only runs while the debugger is attached (using `if (Debugger.IsAttached) { ... }`)

Some things to avoid that slow the execution down in a *debug build compared to a release build* (Regardless if you run inside Visual Studio or execute the file directly):

- Using compiler directives to conditionally include code by by checking if the conditional compilation symbol `DEBUG` is defined (using `#if DEBUG ... #endif`)
- Using members in the [System.Diagnostics.Debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Debug.aspx) class (such as using the `WriteLine`-method a lot or passing objects that have slow overrides of the `ToString`-method).
- Even if none of the above applies, a debug build is slower since:

  - a debug build [emits additional code when compiled to CIL to facilitate debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7672624/1105687). (However I'm not sure this will cause noticeable performance degradation unless you actually attach a debugger to the process).
  - a release build will optimize the code.

*Note that my answers assume that default configurations are in use.* (For instance it's possible to disable code optimization for release builds and to enable code optimization for debug builds).